# monitor change in property in angular

Tags: angular

```
  import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  import { QuizService } from './quiz.service';
  import { timer } from 'rxjs'; 
  import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  questions : any;
```

check on this vlaue

```
  countdown; 
   count=30;
  selectedQuestion;
```

displays currently selected question

```
 counter=0;
```

keeping track of score

```
 score= 0;
 selectedvalue;
 length;
```

quiz service gets all the questions

```
constructor(private quiz: QuizService ){
 }
ngOnInit(){
 this.quiz.getQuestions().subscribe(
 (res) =>{
 this.questions = res;
 this.length= this.questions.length;

 if(!this.selectedQuestion) {
  this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[0];
 }

  }
 )
  this.countdown = timer(0,1000).pipe(
      take(this.count),
      map(()=> --this.count)
   );
 }
```

collecting value of answer selected

```
  onchange(e){
   this.selectedvalue =e.target.value;

   }
```

next function for getting another question after 30 seconds

```
   next(){


 if(this.selectedvalue === this.selectedQuestion.Answer) {
  this.score = this.score +10;

 }
   if(this.counter < this.questions.length -1) {
   this.selectedQuestion = this.questions[this.counter + 1];
    this.counter++;
   }else{
    this.counter++;
   }


    }




      }
```

AS soon as coundown hits 0 i want to execute next function and turn on timer again how can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Use a setter :

```js
private _countdown;

get countdown() { return this.countdown; }
set countdown(value) {
  this.countdown = value;
  if (this.countdown === 0) { this.next(); /* And turn the timer on, however you do it */ }
}
```

Comment: how can i track countdown to zero and then execute next function is there any way i can track property value in angular ts file continously

Comment: i have achieved with help of ngDoCheck thanks for the help

Comment: You are relying on Angular's lifecycle, which means that i's heavy processing. But sure, if you want to be stubborn, be my guest. Good luck with your project.

Comment: That's usually what happens when you don't try it.

Comment: bro find a life this is stackoverflow not fb dont fight  here

Comment: I'm not fighting, I'm exposing your hypocrisy. You're basically telling me Typescript doesn't work.